# Get access to user control from a nested master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to get access to a puplic property on a user control from a nested master page?

Let me explain further

I have 3 deep master pages

1. global.master
2. LargeTopNav.master (inherits global.master)
3. LargeTopNav25-50-25.master (inherits LargeTopNav.master)
4. feature.aspx - This page is where I would like to access a custom user control I have on LargeTopNav.master to be able to set a property.

I'm fairly new to .net so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`MasterType` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228274.aspx) you could set on the *feature.aspx* page like e.g.:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/masters/LargeTopNav.master" %>
```

Then, in turn, provide access to the control's property through a property you create in your *LargeTopNav.master* master page class:

```
public partial class LargeTopNavMaster : MasterPage
{
    // ...

    public string ThePropertyOfTheContainedControl
    {
        get { return MyContainedControl.TheProperty; }
        set { MyContainedControl.TheProperty = value; }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Last, in your *feature.aspx* page, access the property of the master page that provides access to the underlying control:

```
public partial class Feature : Page
{
    // ...

    protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        Master.ThePropertyOfTheContainedControl = "Some nice text.";
    }

    // ...
 }
```

Comment: very lost here. MasterType can have two attributes - do I set them to the largeTopNav.master? Then How Do I create the property through the largetopvan.master page class?

Comment: I'm very very new to .net I know enough to be dangerous :)

Comment: @nkuebelbeck I've added the example from the MSDN page, see above.

Comment: the property is of type enum.  So does the class need to be enum instead of string?

Comment: its complaining about missing } after the first 'set'

Comment: @nkuebelbeck Switch your project from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Generally what I do in this scenario is make your master page implement an interface (which will have the property for your user control), and then from your page `feature.aspx` use `this.Master` (or `this.Master.Master`, make sure to check for `null`) to get a reference to the master page.

Then, just typecast the master page to your interface, and access the property.